# onMouseLeave - gauge chart component size increases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, popover

I am facing an issue with the react-gauge-chart library in my react project.

I have implemented a popover component using material-ui and introduced the gauge chart component from the library inside the popover modal. On text hover gauge chart is been displayed correctly but during onmouseleave event, the popover component flicks(size of gauge chart increases) for a tiny bit second then closes the popover modal. This flicker is currently effecting our project UI.

When I test without the gaugechart there is no issue with the onmouseleave event. Could anyone please help me where am I going wrong here or a solution which I can use?
As I am new to CSS I am not able to understand where this issue is coming from.

Reproduced the issue here
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-over-issue-5ibv6

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `onmouseleave` event is not the cause of this problem. If you change [toggling popups to click](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-over-issue-forked-okpw4?file=/demo.js) you continue to get this behavior

This is a rendering issue. When the popup is closed, the content size is decreased and this causes this behavior

Comment: Thanks for the response. But how can I solve this rendering issue. Is there a way to fix this issue permanently?